# MAPBOX Android Studio cannot get user's location

Tags: java, android, gradle, location, mapbox

I am new in Android Studio. I am developing an app using Mapbox. Their documentation is good and I do understand a lot there. But proceeding in the development, (especially in GETTING USER'S LOCATION) I have encountered this ...

```
[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-shadow'
[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-accuracy-layer'
[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-stroke-layer'
[Render]: can't find source for layer 'mapbox-location-layer'
```

It just keep repeating like this ...

[image]

I have been working to solve this for almost 5 days. I am also new here in Stackoverflow that is why asking a question here is not my option but looking for answer is what I keep on doing.

Here are some of the files that might be needed for lookup ...

My App:build.gradle files ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

My moudle:build.gradle files ...

[image]
[image]

My AndroidManifest ...

[image]

I have followed all the instructions in getting user's location. It was like a copy paste from here ... [LocationPlugin link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/plugins/LocationPluginActivity.java)

Android studio version: 3.1.2

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow, kindly please, follow [mcve] and for better impact, look for [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put at least your code straightly to the question as the text to the code block, instead the images, as well the logs if possible, and in something really needs to be the image, then paste it as a image not a link, thank you in advance.

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx I want to but it say you need 10 reputations.

Comment: Ah, not so fine, but ok then.. Please do it, if it will be possible in the future :)

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx waiting to have 10 reputation and I will edit it. :)

Comment: You don't need 10 reputation to remove all these images and paste code as formatted blocks. [Please do so](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (I have not voted).